# Android orientation change removes actionbar tab custom view

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-tabs

I have created `ActionBar` tabs with custom views. I am using a custom view because I want to show unread badge counts inside the tabs. When the activity is created, they appear just fine.

[image]

When I change the orientation of the device, the selected tab's custom view is removed from the tab.

[image]

This does not occur when I am using a tablet, just a phone. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Here is the custom view I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivTabIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_messages" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBadgeCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/ivTabIcon"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/ivTabIcon"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_message_notification"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="17sp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="4dp"
        android:text="@null"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code when I inflate the custom views

```
RelativeLayout messageView = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_message, null);
ImageView messageIcon = (ImageView) inboxView.findViewById(R.id.ivTabIcon);
messageIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_messages);
TextView tabBadgeInbox = (TextView) inboxView.findViewById(R.id.tvBadgeCount);
actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(messageView);
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the screen shot of the ActionBar when the activity is created

[image]

And when I change orientation here is what the ActionBar looks like

[image]

Now if I create the Activity in landscape mode, the ActionBar loads properly

[image]

Comment: If you could post a screen shot of your whole action bar in both orientations, if it's not doing it on the tablet, but only on the phone, my best guess is that other elements in the action bar are creating too small of a space for the elements inside the relativelayout to be displayed.

Comment: I have updated my post with the screen shots. I have modified some of the icons.